# Map a number to a string

Tags: r

I have vector c(1,3,4,5,7).
I want convert it in this way: 
c('apple','pie','nuts','cookies','some_other_class')

Do you have any short ways to do it? Like a switch method or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:

```
  y <- factor(levels = c(1,3,4,5,7), 
              labels = c('apple','pie','nuts','cookies','some_other_class')
             )
```